# Pandas loc() with custom date function

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe like this:
df =

| index | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/1/2022 | 100 |
| 2 | 12/2/2022 | 200 |
| 3 | 12/5/2022 | 500 |
| 4 | 12/6/2022 | 150 |

I'm trying to create a variable that is the sum of values where the date is within 7 business days of a given date (12/12/2022 in this example).

I was able to do 7 days (not only business days) using this function:

```
var = df.loc[(df['Date'] - date(2022,12,12)).dt.days.abs() < 7, 'Value'].sum()
```

Now I have a function that finds the number of business days between two dates:

```
def date_diff(date_1, date_2):
    dates = []
    if date_2 > date_1:
        delta = (date_2 - date_1).days
        start_date = date_1
    else:
        delta = (date_1 - date_2).days
        start_date = date_2
    for i in range(delta + 1):
        date_ = start_date + timedelta(i)
        if check(date_): # checks if its a business day
            dates.append(date_)
    return len(dates)
```

So this function won't take a Pandas Series and I don't know what to change to make it work. I fiddled with different syntaxes I've used like passing the Series with .dt or .values but nothing has worked. I'm assuming there is an easy solution I'm just overlooking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as a work around, you can use .apply method to flag the wanted days and then use that flag (which would be a new column) to filter the ones you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date':['12/1/2022','12/2/2022','12/5/2022','12/6/2022'],
'Value':[100,200,500,150]
}, index=range(1, 5))
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
print(df)

def addBusDays(dt, n):
    new = dt
    incr = 1 if n >= 0 else -1
    mag = n if n >= 0 else -n
    busDays = 0
    while busDays < mag:
        new += pd.to_timedelta(incr, unit='D')
        if len(pd.bdate_range(new, new)): # checks if its a business day
            busDays += 1
    return new

given = pd.to_datetime('12/12/2022')
var = df.loc[(addBusDays(given, -7) < df['Date']) & (df['Date'] < addBusDays(given, 7)), 'Value'].sum()
print(f'\n{var=}')
```

Output:

```
        Date  Value
1 2022-12-01    100
2 2022-12-02    200
3 2022-12-05    500
4 2022-12-06    150

var=850
```

Explanation:

- find the bounds of the date range within 7 business days of the given date
- use `loc` to filter only those rows with `Date` values that are within the bounds
- use `sum` to aggregate the `Value` column for qualifying rows.

Note:

- The particular implementation of the `addBusDays` function can be changed (for example, see the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150087/add-business-days-to-pandas-dataframe-with-dates-and-skip-over-holidays-python) for alternative approaches). The key concept in my answer to OP's question is that you can pre-calculate the range of qualifying dates and use vectorized pandas comparison operators to filter the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the weekends out adding a second condition to the mask:

```
var = df.loc[((df['Date'] - date(2022,12,12)).dt.days.abs() < 7) & (df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday() not in [5,6])), 'Value'].sum()
```